# How can I turn off cached requests in Visual Studio load test

Tags: load, mstest, testing

When running a load test I want to turn off cached requests.

My web test has the Cache Control setting turned off, which is supposed to mean don't cache.  However, it looks like it is caching the images etc; which I don't want.

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is set by the "Percentage of New Users" setting in the scenario properties.  To ensure that there is no caching, set the property to 100.  Which indicates that 100% of the simulated users will appear to be coming at the site for the first time.

Comment: Be aware that this setting has another possibly unexpected side effect if you are using an Initialize and/or Terminate test in the Test Mix.  When "Percentage of New Users" is 100%, all users do this for each test iteration (apologies for the lack of formatting):  `Initialize > Test Iteration > Terminate > Initialize > Test Iteration > Terminate... etc...`  When set at 0%, all users do this:  `Initialize > Test Iteration > Test Iteration > Test Iteration > ...etc... > Terminate`